# Ecto Query groupping

Tags: database, postgresql, elixir, ecto

Do you see an opportunity to group these results by `location_schedule.id`?

```
from(
  ta in TerminalApplication,
  where: [device_id: ^terminal_id],
  join: d in assoc(ta, :device),
  join: ou in assoc(d, :organization_unit),
  left_join: ls in LocationSchedule,
  on: ou.id == ls.organization_unit_id,
  select: %{terminal_application: ta, location_schedule: ls}
)
```

OR:

```
from(
  ls in LocationSchedule,
  join: ou in assoc(ls, :organization_unit),
  join: d in assoc(ou, :devices),
  right_join: ta in assoc(d, :terminal_applications),
  where: ta.device_id == ^terminal_id,
  select: %{terminal_application: ta, location_schedule: ls}
)
```

These queries return the same result, I need to fetch a LocationSchedule and it's TerminalApplications.

The association is as follows:

```
TerminalApplication (device_id)
BELONGS TO
Device (organization_unit_id)
BELONGS TO
Organization
HAS ONE
LocationSchedule (organization_unit_id)
```

Comment: SQL query would return a plain row set. If you want to group inside DB, you need the aggregate function for TerminalApplication. OTOH, you might get the result as you do and then group by LocationSchedule on the application side.

Comment: This is exactly what I do now :)

Comment: There is no silver bullet; without aggregate function it’s impossible to accomplish in the DB, it simply cannot return an OLAP cube.